How to measure the voltages of a three-phase generator
I have a three-phase generator and I want to measure the voltages of each of the phases, but I don't have a neutral point. How would I connect the phases to an ADC, and how would I make a voltage divider to step-down the voltage?

What are the voltages of the phases supposed to be? You can get a reasonable approximation by dividing the phase-to-phase voltage by the square root of 3.

70V Maximum in practice probably quite a bit lower

Make a "pseudo" neutral point (at least 6 resistors) and measure with this point.


how would I make a voltage divider to step-down the voltage?


How would I connect the phases to ADC?

Make a neutral yourself.
Something like this circuit could be used.
Care for maximum voltages and powers ...
If voltages are lower than 150 Vpp, then one 1 Meg resistor would be enough (in place of 3 serial).
Should change also the resistors R10, R11, and R12, so 6 resistors needed.
Made with microcap v12.

And va, vb, vc are the wiring points to ADCx.

Since you don't have a neutral point you can't measure phase-neutral voltages. You need to measure phase-phase voltages.
One way to do this safely is to make a small delta-star (delta-wye) transformer setup using off-the-shelf single-phase transformers.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
V1, V2 and V3 will not be in phase with L1, L2 and L3 but that isn't a requirement in your question.
Select the transformer primary voltages to suit. For 70 VRMS, 120 V primaries would be suitable and readily available.
The transformer secondary will depend on your measurement signal conditioning circuit.

Use transformers, you only need two

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
the voltage of the the third phase is simply the sum the other two readings.
